# Matlab: int32(2)/int32(3) gives 1. How to get normal integer division?

Tags: matlab

When I'm porting code from a language such as C++, Java, Python into Matlab, and need it to behave in the same way with integers.

int32(n) doesn't work with division (see title of post). Is there a type that does?

**Edit:** Guess what, it turns out that my favourite languages are not as consistent as I thought. C++:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    #define TEST(a, b)  printf("%d / %d = %d\n", (a), (b), (a)/(b));
    TEST(-4, 3);
    TEST(4, -3);
    TEST(-5, 3);
    TEST(5, -3);
    TEST(-1, 2);
    TEST(1, -2);
    return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
-4 / 3 = -1
4 / -3 = -1
-5 / 3 = -1
5 / -3 = -1
-1 / 2 = 0
1 / -2 = 0
```

Python:

```
def TEST(a, b): return (a)/(b)

>>> TEST(-4, 3);
-2
>>> TEST(4, -3);
-2
>>> TEST(-5, 3);
-2
>>> TEST(5, -3);
-2
>>> TEST(-1, 2);
-1
>>> TEST(1, -2);
-1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By "normal integer division", I take it you mean "floor division", like what the other languages do?

In that case, use `idivide` with an explicit rounding option:

```
> idivide(int32(2), int32(3), 'floor')
ans = 0
```

Comment: Matlab is the only language I know that does it differently by default. In other words, weirdly. As opposed to normal, which is what is engrained so much that is not even questioned as you read your code looking for a bug. It seems that whenever there is an arbitrary decision to make, Matlab designers chose to go against the grain: index-base-1, not-equals using "~=", and now this.

Comment: Standard comment: if you're comparing to C++, floor is correct for integers greater than 0, ceil is correct for integers less than 0. It truncates which has the effect of rounding towards 0.

Comment: Careful with unsigned integer overflows. They saturate instead of having the effect of a mod operation.

Comment: This answer works for Python. For C++, replace `'floor'` with `'fix'`.

Comment: Here is a shorthand for the above: `div = @(a, b) idivide(int32(a), int32(b), 'floor')`. Use like this: `div(2, 3)`.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev It always surprises me how little people actually know of the history of languages, and judge other languages based solely on differences in these roots. Python, Java, C++ all have their roots in C, a language designed for and by computer people. 0-based indexing, row-major, etc. Matlab comes from FORTRAN, a language derived from notations commonly found in mathematics. 1-based indexing, column-major, etc. Not better, not worse, just different; a different school of thought. The fact that you dislike it is mainly because you're used to the C-style of thinking.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I didn't realise that (1) Matlab is ancient (2) Fortran has 1-based indexing. So fair enough, back when the design choices were made, arguments such as "similar to mathematical notation" seemed weighty. And you can't have non-backward-compatible changes. What's needed for convergence is something in spirit like Matlab, but with prevalent conventions (i.e. C-derived, as  the size of the population of programmers in each school of thought indicates), which can make use of Matlab code. Just as Jython is Python driving Java, surely Python could also drive Matlab?

Comment: Python already has a number-crunching library called NumPy, which is a pretty decent choice for doing maths in Python.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: My thoughts exactly :) Many people (probably such as yourself) turn less and less to Matlab/Octave and more and more to NumPy/SciPy/Matplotlib for exactly the reasons you specified. It has its drawbacks though, such as being open source and GPL2 (yes, that *can* be a drawback) and less mathematically rigorous at places (arrays can change shape to fit the programmers needs rather than make the math correct, and others), which is why many institutions and companies will keep on using Matlab.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: And don't you think it's a bit shortsighted to say "Most people in the world speak English now, so let's just get rid of all the other languages and move forward"? You know the problems with this statement...1) C-derived languages are not as prevalent as you might think 2) Legacy code will not disappear overnight 3) countless other reasons that I won't type in a comment.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis With natural languages, it's different. Hard to explain, let's say each language gives the speaker a different mind. That at least has entertainment value, because one gets access to more types of humour. My agenda is more about using my favourite language for a project, instead of being forced to use something else. This is frustrating because things like function calling conventions and data structures can be translated perfectly between different programming languages (whereas, by the way, translation between natural languages is lossy).

Comment: @nneonneo I'd use it, but the software package I'm working with only has bindings to Matlab.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev: Natural languages and programming languages are not as dissimilar as you pose; programming is an art, not a science. For instance, there are constructs in Matlab that would be hard to translate to C, for example, the much-debated nested function construct. Although not impossible, the elegance and usefulness of the (multiply) nested function would be completely lost in translation. These and many other constructs make it very non-trivial to translate Matlab, Python, IDL etc. to C, which is why at best you'll see compilers-to-machine language for *subsets* of these languages.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I was talking about being able to call functions across languages and translate data structures. Where it's possible, and fail gracefully where it's not (for example, where an argument to a function is a function pointer; in fact whenever there is a difficulty in mapping from language A to language B). Not asking a lot. This can be done now, of course, but it's a big hassle. What's needed is a standard that can be supported by all languages and compilers.